# Не получается экранировать символ. Java

Tags: java

[image: Экранирование]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция SyllableSwitch возвращает слово с разделенными слогами.
К примеру:
суслик - сус|лик
коммунизм - ком|му|низм

Хотел посредством Split'а хотел разделить на массив String'ов. 
Но вот символ вертикальной черты не подается в параметр Сплита. Думал надо экранировать, но Яве все равно что - то не нравится.

Comment: split("\\|"); - попробуйте

Comment: Вместо скриншотов следует добавить текстовые фрагменты кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @GinTasan за ответ! Вот так получилось разделить.

`Syllable = SyllablesSwitch(text, lang).split("\\|");`